# Close navigation drawer after click on item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a University project and trying to implement a feature that allows the navigation drawer to close whenever I click on one of the items in it. However, I'm not sure how to handle this.

```
    <template>
  <div id="navigation-mobile">
    <Searchbar class="search"/>
    <ul v-for="item in tabs"
            :key="item.path"
            active-class
            @click="$router.push(item.path)"
    >
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mobile-footer">
      <ul>
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here's what I have in App.vue, which contains a part of the nav-drawer:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <NavBarMobile v-if="mobileView"/>
    <div class="content" :class="{'open': showNav}">
      <div style="height:20px"></div>
      <div id="navigation-icon" v-if="mobileView"
      @click="showNav = !showNav">
        <v-icon medium dark>menu</v-icon>
      </div>
      <NavBar v-if="!mobileView"></NavBar>
      <v-content class="pa-0" transition="slide-x-transition"></v-content>
      <Footer v-if="!mobileView"></Footer>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

This is my code so far. I would like to use a @click, I think that would be the most efficient way to do that, but I don't know if I can, since I'm already using it. I'm not very good at programming. Any suggestions?

Here's the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/gameshelf-0209-jack-forked-zobe5

You can find the component in NavBarMobile.vue

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve this. The simplest, in my opinion, would be to simply "watch" the `$route` object from within your `App.vue`:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.showNav = false
    }
  }
}
```

The `watch` property on the Vue instance contains functions that will watch for changes to variables of the same name. Upon change, the function is run.

More on watchers and computed properties: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

**EDIT**: Some extra info about reacting to Router changes: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: Thank you, it worked flawlessly! And thank you very much for the links, I'll check them out right now!

Comment: @StefanoPrimerano Glad it worked! Best of luck with your app. I love the style of the whole app! :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve it is by emitting an event from the child component.

- first point the click event to a method to handle your logic  like so :

```html
<ul v-for="item in tabs" :key="item.path" active-class @click="redirect(item.path)">
```

- then add a method in your script to emit a custom event from your NavBarMobile component :

```js
methods: {
        redirect(path) {
            this.$router.push(path)
            this.$emit('change', false)
        }
    },
```

- and finally listen for this event from the parent component:

```html
<NavBarMobile v-if="mobileView" @change="showNav = $event"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative! It gave me a wider perspective on how to solve this problem.

Comment: My pleasure  And I don't think that your comment about not being good at programming is relevant 